# Using regex in python for html tags

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, urllib

I am trying to read through an html doc using python and gather all of the table rows into a single list. (I am aware of specialized tools for this purpose, but I must use regex.) 
Here is my code so far:

```
import urllib
import re
URL = 'http://www.xpn.org/events/concert-calendar'
sock = urllib.urlopen( URL )
doc = sock.read()
sock.close()
patString = r'''
    < tr(. * ?)>
    (.*?)
    < /tr>
    '''
pattern = re.compile(patString, re.VERBOSE)
concerts = re.findall(pattern, doc)
print (concerts)
```

However, the print is only printing an empty list. I have tried a few different patterns but all have produced the same result.  I'm pretty sure that the issue is the pattern, but I'm not entirely sure (as I am trying to become accommodated with python while writing this.) the table rows I am trying to find have the format `<tr class="odd/even"> other data </tr>` and I would like to capture all of this data and place it into a list for use later in the script.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: `I must use regex.` really? i am curious as too why?

Comment: `. * ?` literally parses any character, followed by an unlimited amount of space, followed by possibly one more space.  Is that what you meant to type?

Comment: Newlines in your data?  Try `pattern = re.compile(patString, re.VERBOSE|re.DOTALL)`.

Comment: @BaileyS:  `re.VERBOSE` directs the regex parser to ignore all unescaped whitespace.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ah, I came at this question from the regex tag.

Comment: @njzk2 yeah,  I know it's weird. Its for an assignment in school.  Once I have the regex working,  I will be fine.

Comment: for starters, the `tr` are written `<tr>`, not `< tr>` no space there, other wise the html is not valid.

Comment: then, what do you expect `(. * ?)` to do?

Comment: also, you should put your regex on 1 line, the spaces are line return are part of the expression

Comment: @njzk2 that is for the data in-between the tags.

Comment: @njzk2 for both cases?   The only reason I had it there was to keep it from getting greedy.

Comment: You probably need `.*?`, otherwise the matching could escape from the `<>` and match more than one tag at a time.

Comment: Also, instead of using `<tr(.*?)>`, it would be more safe to use `<tr([^>]*?)>`.  That way it's guaranteed to not "escape" the tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @njzk2:  Your latest comment is completely incorrect.  `.*?` is valid and correct.  The spaces are acceptable and do not cause a problem here.  They are ignored because the pattern is compiled with the `re.VERBOSE` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matches your sample data just fine.  If the data runs on multiple lines, turn on the option for `.` to match `\n`.  That option is `re.DOTALL` by the way.

```
<tr(.*?)>(.*?)</tr>
```

The `?` qualification for the data in the middle is pretty important, otherwise it could match entire `<tr></tr>` blocks as the data part.

It is easy because you are not parsing HTML, but instead just trying to extract some tags in a very specific case.

Things will get ugly if you have a `<tr>` in a `<tr>` for example.

Comment: I was going for re.MULTILINE, but re.DOTALL is much better in this case

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks for the help.  Accepting this answer.

Comment: Also it is worth noting that i used <tr([^>] *?) > for the first tag.

Comment: @AaronC Excluding the `>` character from the match is a pretty good idea actually... a bit more explicit than the non-greedy match.  The whole `re.VERBOSE` thing seems kind of weird to me, because everywhere else, pretty much always, white space matters in a regex.  If you are learning the language for the first time, do yourself a favor and turn it off. `[^>] *` is truly difficult for my mind to accept as right, even though it works with the ignored white space.